# Share Point is a kind of Cloud computing?

Tags: sharepoint, cloud

I study about cloud computing, i understand that we have types of cloud computing:Private, Public and Hybrid Clouds, i have question about cloud, the Share Point is a kind of Cloud computing(private cloud computing)?

Thank You

Comment: This is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

No. SharePoint - it's a platform for collaboration, document management, enterprise portals and many more. You can read about here: [What is SharePoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/what-is-sharepoint-HA010378184.aspx).

Microsoft also offering SaaS solution - Office 365, with SharePoint Online included in some of plans. It's a cloud, but not cloud computing - it's a software as a service.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint in Microsoft 365 A cloud-based service, hosted by Microsoft, for businesses of all sizes. SharePoint Server Organizations can deploy and manage SharePoint Server on-premises or with an Office 365 Enterprise subscription to take advantage of all the latest features.